# Decoupling player movement from external forces in physics engine

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, simulation, game-physics

I have a rigid-body physics engine for a game I'm creating, and am unsure of how to implement player movement with it.

The ideal behavior I want is as follows:

- Player participates properly in collisions, i.e. no direct manipulation of position
- Player can start/stop almost instantly, at a fast acceleration/deceleration to a constant velocity/complete stop
- Forces acting on the player that are external to the player controller should resolve normally, without being affected by whatever is controlling the player fast start/stop
- The player should be able to move to counteract external forces, with the same responsiveness as point #2

Currently, I am able to achieve the first 2 points by adding a constant acceleration on player input, then applying exponential drag. This makes the player eventually reach a max velocity, then decelerate quickly once the movement keys are not pressed.

It feels good and responsive, but any external forces I want to subject the player to will also be quickly diminished because of that drag. Is there any way around this?

The game is in 3D first-person, uses impulse resolution, and is coded in C++, if relevant.

Comment: how do you want to distinguish between the influence of external forces that shouldn't be subject to drag and velocity changes that should be? for instance, if the player changes the required movement direction, i assume you want it to change pretty quickly (according to point 2), but at this stage you don't know if the velocity along the old direction comes from a movement request (and thus must be suppressed quickly) or from some external forces. essentially, movement request is also a force that changes the player's momentum, and once it's done it's hard to separate it from the rest.

Comment: that's exactly the problem i'm unable to solve. both the external forces and forces from movement requests need to be taken together to properly participate in the simulation, and yet have to be separated for me to selectively apply drag.

i never thought that this would prove harder than implementing a physics engine.

Comment: what i'm saying is that i don't think it *can* be solved the way you want. if the player is able to change movement direction fast, he should be able to counteract external forces equally efficiently. you can only fake it maybe by making the player's damping (drag) temporarily weaker if you detect external influences